# Mirrored DB on Restoring state after removing Mirroing also

Tags: mirroring

We done Mirroring of MS SQL data base to other system without witness on synchronize mode. When I Remove mirroring(not pausing , not fail over) by manually My Mirrored Database still continuing in Restoring state

Comment: Did you try to bring the database online by issuing - RESTORE DATABASE <DATABASE_NAME> WITH RECOVERY

Comment: Thanks for the Help it Worked. But how / is there any option by which can I Bring that DB(Mirrored DB ) back to restoring mode , where state of DB will be Restoring instead of Online, without taking whole Principle DB back up and restore it with no recovery option for Mirroring

Comment: No - once you use WITH RECOVERY, you cannot put the remote database back to restoring without taking another backup and restoring it WITH NORECOVERY.  I guess I'm confused as to what you're trying to achieve.  Are you trying to 'access' data in the mirrored database without bringing in online?  You'd have to use a database snapshot which is Enterprise only

Comment: OK thanks for the help again .  I am trying to make the Mirrored data base online when My Principle have any issue.

Comment: I think you're talking about a manual failover to the mirror - see this link - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189850.aspx

Comment: Also this link - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179481.aspx

Answer (score 2):

That is normal. When you setup a database mirroring the mirror database is on no recovery/restoring mode and copies and run transaction executed on primary server. Then when you remove the database mirroring you just stopped those transaction to be transferred and nothing is happened to bring it back to recovery mode. If you want your secondary (mirror) database to be active you have to execute.

```
      RESTORE DATABASE YourDatabaseName  WITH RECOVERY
```